# Get-WMIObject twice in one simple script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Have this script but I am additionally trying to get  Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computer $server | Select SystemName, caption, CreationClassName  details out as well. How can I combine this with the script below so I can get Computer name, OS & Architecture results for Win 7/2008 and Win 2003 32 bit machines.

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Servers.txt
$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $server | select-object csname, caption, OSArchitecture}
$results
```

The above works but doesnt display 32Bit for the machines that are running 2003 and are 32 bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Servers.txt
$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $info = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $server | select csname, caption, OSArchitecture
  gwmi Win32_Processor -Computer $server | % {
    $info | Add-Member 'SystemName' -Type NoteProperty -Value $_.SystemName
    $info | Add-Member 'CPU' -Type NoteProperty -Value $_.Caption
    $info | Add-Member 'CreationClassName' -Type NoteProperty -Value $_.CreationClassName
  }
  $info
}
$results
```

Comment: Wanrings displayed but it does work and gives the info perfectly. Thank you :)